# Backup color for incompatible background image stretching

Tags: html, css, background

I've got a stretched background image in a TD using the background-size and background-repeat CSS properties.  Several recently older browsers do not support this, though (including IE9 which is supposed to support it as I understand).
Anyway, that's all fine, but I'm looking for a way to set a 'backup' solid color.  background-color seems to be overridden by the image, so it just shows an unstretched image at the top-left over a white background.  Is there a way to get the background color below it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use background to set it:

`background:url(img/bg.jpg) top left no-repeat #5F5F5F;`

That should work.

Comment: That did it, although looking at your code, I realized the real issue was that I was passing only a URL to background, not background-image.

Comment: Aha! :P next time show some code so we can spot the error immediately ;-)